# AngularJS Ui-grid DataTables, how to avoid multi ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

Here is the problem,

I made some kind of people listing with angularJS.
People are JSON objects that look like this :

```
{ "id":"0" , "name":"My name" , "firstname":"My first Name" , "contacts":[{"id":"0" , "type":"phone" , "value":"0574869345"},{"id":"1" , "type":"email" , "myEmail@mail.com"}] }
```

Notice that the person may have several contact informations (emails, phones, etc...)

I was actually able to display the people list (array) into a "simple" table with :

1. ng-repeat on "persons" (people in peopleList)
2. ng-repeat on "contacts" (contact in people.contacts)

This sounds somehow like the most logical & easy solution. BUT in some other cases, with less complex data, I am working with the "ng-grid", which is now "ui-grid" to display data-tables.

And, before that, I used to work with jquery.dataTables but seems like it does not fit angular since it is directly related to a js var, and is not "updated" on $scope changes... As you probably got it, user will be able to "change" people list on event. So the grid / table contents have to be linked to the scope.

Here is a very shortened/simplified example of the current "only angular" solution I am trying to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/k2p3xxhx/

Here is the ng-grid solution (**not working**!) which I'd like to use if possible : http://jsfiddle.net/guprs47p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular UI grid allows you to bind custom templates.
You can achieve what you need using cell template property for your field.

You can use cellTemplate, which is nothing but your custom HTML for rendering data.

```
<div ng-repeat='field in COL_FIELD'>
  <div>{{field.id}} - {{field.type}}- {{field.value}}</div>
 </div>
```

Now since you have your template, you can assign to your field (which is nothing but a column in UI Grid) using its cellTemplate property, so your field object would look like below,

```
  {
  field: "contacts",
  displayName: "Contacts",
  cellTemplate: "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'><div ng-repeat='field in COL_FIELD'>{{field.id}} - {{field.type}}- {{field.value}}</div></div>"
}
```

You can see, there is `COL_FIELD` on which the data will be iterated, this `COL_FIELD` will have the actual value while binding the data. So you know the actual value is an array which can be iterated using `ng-repeat`.

So when the ui grid renders, it will iterate over your data and display values.

Below I have used the same example as yours to create sample based on your need.

More on custom templates you can find on UI Grid's [official site](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates)

Hope it helps !

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.grid']);

function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {
    data: "listing",
    columnDefs: [{
      field: "id",
      displayName: "ID"
    }, {
      field: "name",
      displayName: "Name"
    }, {
      field: "firstname",
      displayName: "First Name"
    }, {
      field: "contacts",
      displayName: "Contacts",
      cellTemplate: "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'><div ng-repeat='field in COL_FIELD'>{{field.id}} - {{field.type}}- {{field.value}}</div></div>"
    }, ],
    rowHeight: 100
  }
  $scope.listing = [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "My name",
    "firstname": "My first Name",
    "contacts": [{
      "id": "0",
      "type": "phone",
      "value": "0574869345"
    }, {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "email",
      "value": "myEmail@mail.com"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "My name One",
    "firstname": "My first Name One",
    "contacts": [{
      "id": "2",
      "type": "phone",
      "value": "0574444444"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "email",
      "value": "myEmailOne@mail.com"
    }]
  }];
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.switch = function() {
    if ($scope.count % 2 == 0) {
      $scope.listing = [{
        "id": "0",
        "name": "My name",
        "firstname": "My first Name",
        "contacts": [{
          "id": "0",
          "type": "phone",
          "value": "0574869345"
        }, {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "email",
          "value": "myEmail@mail.com"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "My name One",
        "firstname": "My first Name One",
        "contacts": [{
          "id": "2",
          "type": "phone",
          "value": "0574444444"
        }, {
          "id": "3",
          "type": "email",
          "value": "myEmailOne@mail.com"
        }]
      }];
    } else {
      $scope.listing = [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "My name Two",
        "firstname": "My first Name Two",
        "contacts": [{
          "id": "4",
          "type": "phone",
          "value": "0888888888"
        }, {
          "id": "5",
          "type": "email",
          "value": "myEmailTwo@mail.com"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "My name Three",
        "firstname": "My first Name Three",
        "contacts": [{
          "id": "6",
          "type": "phone",
          "value": "022222222"
        }, {
          "id": "7",
          "type": "email",
          "value": "myEmailThree@mail.com"
        }]
      }];
    }
    $scope.count++;
    console.log('switched!');
  };
}
```

```css
.uiGridTable: {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="switch();">Switch</button>
  <div ui-grid="myData" class="uiGridTable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really helpful! thanks for your answer. But is it possible to make it act like a "table-responsive" table (from bootstrap) AND add tips that are native in dataTables like the "quick search" input and the possibility to set display to 10 entries or 20 or more/less... with page management ?

Comment: UI grid provides column filtering as well as global filtering. It also provides default sorting and if that doesn't suit your requirements, it has provision to write your own custom algorithm. Yes UI grid supports pagination both client side as well as server side as well as paging (showing number of rows drop downs). You can check the features on official site.